# Blazor Server - Error during adding new Scaffolded Item - Identity

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

During the generation of any page (Adding new Scaffolded Item - Identity) I get such an error, with is not very helpful for me, unfortunately, I didn't generate all pages that I need before that was working correctly.

There was an error running the selected code generator, package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'ProjectName'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating core packages to version 3.1.19 is solving the problem

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI
Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
```

Probably the most important was Identity.UI update.